# Async/await requires promise to be caught?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await, es6-promise

Spent a day debugging strange error. I'm not a master in using async/await, apparently, as this little example shows. I guess its counter-intuitive to me but I didn't expect the following:

```
var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   reject(new Error('some rainy days...'))
})

p
   .then(data => {console.info('data', data)})
   .catch(error => {console.error('inner error', error)})
   .finally(() => {console.info('inner done!')})
   .catch(error => {console.error('outer error', error)})
   .finally(() => {console.info('outer done!')})

async function test (p) {
   try {
      let data = await p
      console.info('async data', data)
      return data
   } catch (error) {
      console.error('async error', error)
      throw error
   } finally {
      console.info('async is done!')
   }
}

test(p)
   .then(data => {console.info('test data', data)})
   .catch(error => {console.error('test error', error)})
   .finally(() => {console.info('test done!')})
```

The output is as follows:

```
inner error Error: some rainy days...
    at Promise (<anonymous>:2:11)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:9
inner done!
async error Error: some rainy days...
    at Promise (<anonymous>:2:11)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:9
async is done!
test error Error: some rainy days...
    at Promise (<anonymous>:2:11)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:9
test done!
outer done!
```

The output is not unexpected. However, I did not expect to be required to use `.catch` prior and inside the `async` method. If I omit all `.catch`, `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` will be thrown. Code is as follows:

```
var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   reject(new Error('some rainy days...'))
})

p
   .then(data => {console.info('data', data)})
   // .catch(error => {console.error('inner error', error)})
   .finally(() => {console.info('inner done!')})
   // .catch(error => {console.error('outer error', error)})
   .finally(() => {console.info('outer done!')})

async function test (p) {
   try {
      let data = await p
      console.info('async data', data)
      return data
   } catch (error) {
      console.error('async error', error)
      throw error
   } finally {
      console.info('async is done!')
   }
}

test(p)
   .then(data => {console.info('test data', data)})
   .catch(error => {console.error('test error', error)})
   .finally(() => {console.info('test done!')})
```

The output is:

```
async error Error: some rainy days...
    at Promise (<anonymous>:2:11)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:9
async is done!
outer done!
test error Error: some rainy days...
    at Promise (<anonymous>:2:11)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:9
test done!
Uncaught (in promise) Error: some rainy days...
    at Promise (<anonymous>:2:11)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:9
```

My expectation was that `await` would unwrap or catch and throw the error, which would be automatically caught inside `try/catch` block of the `async` function. Otherwise, I'm not sure what is the best way of handling parameters to an `async` method when some can be either promises or scalars.

Obviously, I've got something terribly wrong! Would greatly appreciate if someone could set the record for me straight!

Comment: Your code branches off promise `p`. You have a `p.then().catch().finally()...` branch and, within `test()` an `await p` branch. To get the expected behaviour, assign `p = new Promise(...).then().catch().finally()...`.

Comment: Omg, I think I was just not thinking straight. Thanks for the clear thought and explanation.

Comment: No worries - we've all been there :-(